# Using TypeForwardedTo in C# without creating a circular reference

Tags: c#, dependencies

I'm currently trying to resolve a circular reference within my C# projects. I have two projects: a base project, and then a higher-level project that uses several things from the base project. I'm trying to deprecate several classes within the base project, and have them call methods that are in the higher project.

This causes an issue with circular dependencies. If I keep the obsolete classes in the base project, then it creates a circular dependency with it calling classes within the higher project. However, if I move the obsolete classes to the higher-level project, then, in order to not break backwards compatibility, I must use TypeForwardedTo, which also creates a circular dependency.

Is there any way to prevent a circular dependency in this situation without breaking backwards compatibility?